# PyQt: Button in .UI doesn't show when run

Tags: python, pyqt4

**SOLVED**
I changed:

> self.ui = base_class()

Into:

> self.ui = form_class()
>           self.ui.setupUi(self)

And now it works!

---

I'm trying to get some code working so I can use the .ui file on the fly. This way updates with Qt Designer are immediately used when I run the python code.

After fiddling and using snippets I ended up with the following code. But somehow the button in the .ui doesn't show. Anyone an idea?

```
import sys,os

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

form_class, base_class = uic.loadUiType('try_ui.ui')

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = base_class()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And try_ui.ui a simple button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>323</width>
    <height>111</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>323</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Please post your answer and flag it as the right solution, to help future newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example which shows a message box when you click the button. You of course need the above UI example.

```
import sys,os

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

form_class, base_class = uic.loadUiType('try_ui.ui')

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    MESSAGE = "Hello!"
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = form_class()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.informationMessage)
    def informationMessage(self):
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self,
                "QMessageBox.information()", MainWindow.MESSAGE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

And for the people who like PySide.

```
import sys,os

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtUiTools

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    MESSAGE = "Hello!"
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = loadUi(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "try_ui.ui"), self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.informationMessage)
    def informationMessage(self):
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self,
                "QMessageBox.information()", MainWindow.MESSAGE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You need to include the classes UiLoader and loadUi. They are from: https://github.com/lunaryorn/snippets/blob/master/qt4/designer/pyside_dynamic.py

```
class UiLoader(QtUiTools.QUiLoader):
    """
    Subclass :class:`~PySide.QtUiTools.QUiLoader` to create the user interface
    in a base instance.

    Unlike :class:`~PySide.QtUiTools.QUiLoader` itself this class does not
    create a new instance of the top-level widget, but creates the user
    interface in an existing instance of the top-level class.

    This mimics the behaviour of :func:`PyQt4.uic.loadUi`.
    """

    def __init__(self, baseinstance):
        """
        Create a loader for the given ``baseinstance``.

        The user interface is created in ``baseinstance``, which must be an
        instance of the top-level class in the user interface to load, or a
        subclass thereof.

        ``parent`` is the parent object of this loader.
        """
        QtUiTools.QUiLoader.__init__(self, baseinstance)
        self.baseinstance = baseinstance

    def createWidget(self, class_name, parent=None, name=''):
        if parent is None and self.baseinstance:
            # supposed to create the top-level widget, return the base instance
            # instead
            return self.baseinstance
        else:
            # create a new widget for child widgets
            widget = QtUiTools.QUiLoader.createWidget(self, class_name, parent, name)
            if self.baseinstance:
                # set an attribute for the new child widget on the base
                # instance, just like PyQt4.uic.loadUi does.
                setattr(self.baseinstance, name, widget)
            return widget


def loadUi(uifile, baseinstance=None):
    """
    Dynamically load a user interface from the given ``uifile``.

    ``uifile`` is a string containing a file name of the UI file to load.

    If ``baseinstance`` is ``None``, the a new instance of the top-level widget
    will be created.  Otherwise, the user interface is created within the given
    ``baseinstance``.  In this case ``baseinstance`` must be an instance of the
    top-level widget class in the UI file to load, or a subclass thereof.  In
    other words, if you've created a ``QMainWindow`` interface in the designer,
    ``baseinstance`` must be a ``QMainWindow`` or a subclass thereof, too.  You
    cannot load a ``QMainWindow`` UI file with a plain
    :class:`~PySide.QtGui.QWidget` as ``baseinstance``.

    :method:`~PySide.QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName()` is called on the
    created user interface, so you can implemented your slots according to its
    conventions in your widget class.

    Return ``baseinstance``, if ``baseinstance`` is not ``None``.  Otherwise
    return the newly created instance of the user interface.
    """
    loader = UiLoader(baseinstance)
    widget = loader.load(uifile)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(widget)
    return widget
```